# How to determine in bash if / mountpoint was mounted from other OS?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

Im writing shell script to check if user may be doing some nasty things in Linux enviroment. One check i would like to do is determine if / filesyste was mounted using external OS (like using live SO) in previous mount.

First i think to exec script when boot to get the mount time in previous boot using journalctl and actual last mount using tune2fs, to compare it. But last mount using tune2fs gets current mount, not previous, because system is mounted when ckecks it.

Any idea to solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please be a bit more specific and post the code relevant to the question. As of now, you leave us to do all the guessowrk

Comment: This seems like it might be more appropriate for [unix.se]. You really need to know whether the information is available and where it's stored, the actual programming is a minor detail on top of that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. If you feel the question is on-topic, then see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

`dmesg`'s output shows about the mounting of `/` (and other infos as well). If your current OS's `dmesg`'s output has that info, it was mounted by the current system.

You can use the output of dmesg in your script like :

```
#!/bin/bash
number=$(dmesg | grep -c "sdaN")
if [ $number == 0 ]; then
    echo "It was not mounted by the current system"
else
    echo "It was mounted by the current system"
fi
```